# Can I use actual IMC time for the requirements in 61.109(a)(3)?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, instrument-flight-rules, visual-flight-rules

I needed extra instrument time for my VFR checkride but it was cloudy for my lesson. My CFII and I turned it into an introduction to IFR lesson and we flew 0.3 actual and 0.3 simulated (with the hood) and did 1 ILS approach in IMC.

[61.109(a)(3)](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_1109) says that the following instrument training is required:

> 3 hours of flight training in a single-engine airplane on the control and maneuvering of an airplane solely by reference to
>   instruments, including straight and level flight, constant airspeed
>   climbs and descents, turns to a heading, recovery from unusual flight
>   attitudes, radio communications, and the use of navigation
>   systems/facilities and radar services appropriate to instrument
>   flight;

Is it correct to assume that I can use the IMC time for this?

Comment: Yes, you can. I don't have the FAR to quote, but I put 4 hours of actual instrument (along with 2 actual IFR approaches) towards my VFR PPL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure can.  FAR 61.109 makes no distinction between flight in hard IMC and simulated in an aircraft using a view limiting device.